# ReiserFS NFS for Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, nas, file-server, reiserfs

So I got a new 2TB HDD for Christmas and I wanted to make an NFS with it.

My uncle is a computer nerd, but also a teacher and a little hard to catch for a question, but he showed me  how to set up an XFS network drive while he was here for my birthday. He explained a little to me, so now I know that Windows can't directly access XFS, but it can get it over the network.

Is ReiserFS the same? He also said that XFS isn't the best for small files, like a billion word documents and PDFs.

I was hoping to format maybe a 10GB partition on the drive for this. Any help from you brilliant people? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a NAS that I'm using to act as a central media storage device for my entire house - what I've personally done is take a spare 1TB HDD, make one giant ext4 partition, blanket the drive with permissions of 755, and use samba shares to serve the media to the three Windows machines on my network, as well as my laptop, which is Ubuntu 13.10.

I've used samba across a couple different machines/filesystems, and while I've not tried an XFS personally, I see no issue using it.

TL;DR: Should not matter what kind of partition/filesystem you use, if you're using a tool like Samba to share the files.